# Actionbar not showing with PagerSlidingTabStrip

Tags: android, android-actionbar, pagerslidingtabstrip

I have created a sliding tab by using PagerSlidingTabStrip. it is created correctly but the action bar get lost it is showing like this :

[image]

Is any help me on this why action bar is disabled.

```
import com.astuetz.PagerSlidingTabStrip;


public class SMainTabActivity extends FragmentActivity implements ETabFragment.OnFragmentInteractionListener,
    MTabFragment.OnFragmentInteractionListener{

public String classSelected;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_INDETERMINATE_PROGRESS);
    setProgressBarIndeterminateVisibility(true);
    setProgressBarIndeterminateVisibility(false);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_subject_main_tab);

    Bundle b = getIntent().getExtras();
    classSelected = b.getString("classId");
  // Get the ViewPager and set it's PagerAdapter so that it can display items
    ViewPager viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
    viewPager.setAdapter(new TabFragmentPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager()));

    // Give the PagerSlidingTabStrip the ViewPager
    PagerSlidingTabStrip tabsStrip = (PagerSlidingTabStrip) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
    // Attach the view pager to the tab strip
    tabsStrip.setViewPager(viewPager);

}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.activity_main_actionsbar, menu);

    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);


   // getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main_actionsbar, menu);
    //return true;
}
```

xml (activity_subject_main_tab):

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">

<com.astuetz.PagerSlidingTabStrip
    android:id="@+id/tabs"
    app:pstsShouldExpand="true"
    app:pstsTextAllCaps="true"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="48dp"
    android:textSize="14sp"
    android:textColor="#000000"
    app:pstsDividerColor="@color/color1"
    app:pstsIndicatorColor="@color/color2"
    app:pstsUnderlineColor="@color/color3"
    app:pstsTabPaddingLeftRight="14dp">
</com.astuetz.PagerSlidingTabStrip>

<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/viewpager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@android:color/white" />
```

manifest:

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".SubjectMainTabActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_subject_main_tab" >
    </activity>
</application>
```

Expected is :

[image]

Comment: post the R.layout.activity_subject_main_tab and the manifest code

Comment: Can you post the activity_subject_main_tab.xml?

Comment: Check my answer, maybe what you need

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It could simply be that in your xml file, you made you Actionbar 0dp. Another issue could be that you are not using the right theme for the App. The theme that gets the action bar would be set in your style.xml like so:

```
<style name="MyMaterialTheme" parent="MyMaterialTheme.Base">

</style>

<style name="MyMaterialTheme.Base" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="windowActionBar">true</item>
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
</style>
```

Then to call it in your AndroidManifest.xml, like so:

```
android:theme="@style/MyMaterialTheme"
```

NOTE: You would need to add the colors in the styles.xml to your choosing.
Also, If you are completely stuck, use this example for a better more Android supported Material Design Guide http://www.android4devs.com/2014/12/how-to-make-material-design-app.html

Comment: Hi, i am using this :   <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    </style>

Comment: See my theme style's parent is ...DarkActionBar, it would be the same thing with what you are using, just with more specific needs, You could even remove those color tags entirely and just use the window Tags

Comment: no luck. i have set the theme in style ( <style name="AppThemeAction" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
        <item name="windowActionBar">true</item>

    </style>) and make the entry in manifest  android:theme="@style/AppThemeAction"  but still action bar is missing...

Comment: Ahh, try extending ActionBarActivity instead of FragmentActivity in your SMainTabActivity @itin

Comment: its breaking the code.. java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.Class java.lang.Object.getClass()'  I believe changing the class will require many other changes....

Comment: Yeah you would definitely need to change a few things and add stuffs, but that would be the easiest way of getting Action Bar

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, to solve it just extend ActionBarActivity instead of FragmentActivity and it will work.

Comment: after changing to ActionBarActivity my code is breaking java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.Class java.lang.Object.getClass()'